# How to access BIOS to boot from USB on Lenovo X230i?

Tags: boot, windows-10, bios, thinkpad, lenovo-laptop

I cannot enter BIOS when the laptops turns on so that I can boot Ubuntu from a USB pendrive.

I've tried to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> as suggested on some webpages as well as randomly press function keys just after the machine turns on.

I cannot find anything online and <kbd>F1</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> doesn't seem to work ([source](https://kb.wisc.edu/page.php?id=58779)).

I don't have **UEFI Firmware Settings** menu available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graphical illustrations for:

- [Windows 8](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/documents/ht081446)
- [Windows 10](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5831-uefi-firmware-settings-boot-inside-windows-10-a.html)

Here's how you can access BIOS:

**Settings** > **Update & recovery**/**Update & security** > **Recovery** > **Advanced startup: Restart now** > **Troubleshoot** > **Advanced options**.

If you see **UEFI Firmware Settings** then go for it.

Otherwise: **Startup Settings** > **Restart** > Tap the BIOS key (<kbd>F1</kbd> in this case)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [guest](https://superuser.com/users/247996/guest) I was able to access the boot menu in BIOS. Here's how.

The point is that you have to just restart your laptop in a way which activates the function keys in the **Welcome Screen**. This is one of the possible ways.

So to boot from a USB drive on Lenovo X230i with Windows 10 installed I had to:

1. Go to **Settings** > **Update & security** > **Recovery**.
2. In the **Advanced startup** section click **Restart now**.
3. The laptop restarts now.
4. Go to **Troubleshoot** > **Advanced options** > **Startup settings**.
5. Click a button to restart the laptop.
6. Hit <kbd>F12</kbd> to directly enter the **Boot menu** as the computer turns on and the *Welcome Screen* shows up.

   [image: The Welcome Screen]
   <sup>*The Welcome Screen (I don't know what the proper name is).*</sup>
7. Choose the device you want to boot from.
8. Done.

As I said, [guest's](https://superuser.com/users/247996/guest) links were extremely helpful. Especially this one: *[the useful link](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/5831-uefi-firmware-settings-boot-inside-windows-10-a.html.)*.

Comment: btw was it accessible on normal restart?

Comment: I dont think so. @guest